# BreezeJS query orderBy length?

Tags: breeze

I have a breeze query to fetch some values from my database.

If I want to order the values alphabetically, then the query looks like this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Words")
.orderBy("Text");
```

The thing is I want to sort the values returned first by length, then alphabetically.

For example, this set of results is ordered alphabetically:

```
a
ab
b
bb
```

How do I make it ordered like this:

```
a
b
ab
bb
```

??

I know I can write a function to order the data the way I want to AFTER it's returned from the server, but I'm wondering if it's possible to change the query so the data will be sorted like described above just by changing the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding an additional filter step on the server before sending the data back to the client.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Word> Words() {
  return ContextProvider.Context.Words.ToList().OrderBy(customOrderByImpl;
}
```

This may be less than performant because with your example I don't think that you can take advantage of any database sorting ( at least thru EF).  This is why the call to ToList occurs before sorting the results in memory on the server.

Hope this makes sense.